# What happens when I use tac and/ or rev to the bits of the file?

Tags: bash

I know that linux commands `tac` and `rev` do different things. I was wondering what happens to the file transformed to each bit when I use `tac` rather than `rev`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `od` to discover what happens to each *byte*, not *bit*.

Here are some examples:

```sh
$ echo -en 'one\ntwo\n'
one
two
$ echo -en 'one\ntwo'
one
two$ # owww, no new line at the end, so the prompt goes on the same line
$ echo -en 'one\ntwo' | tac | od -a
0000000   t   w   o   o   n   e  nl
0000007
$ echo -en 'one\ntwo\n' | tac | od -a
0000000   t   w   o  nl   o   n   e  nl
0000010
$ echo -en 'one\ntwo' | rev | od -a
0000000   e   n   o  nl   o   w   t
0000007
$ echo -en 'one\ntwo\n' | rev | od -a
0000000   e   n   o  nl   o   w   t  nl
0000010
```